# Docker-compose doesn't work on ubuntu 20.04 [permission denied entrypoint.sh]

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04

My `docker-compose` works fine and runs on `Windows 10` but when i tried to run it from `ubuntu 20.04` i get this error:

```
ERROR: for container_web_1  Cannot start service web: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I can't understand why do i get `Permission denied` for `entrypoint.sh`? I use `chmod +x` to avoid this...

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
COPY .. .
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY .. $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem with your Dockerfile. After you create `entrypoint.sh` and do `chmod +x` you then overwrite the permissions with `COPY .. .`. One way to fix it is to put `RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh` line in the very end, right before `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: Also note that you can't `COPY` from a parent directory, so you're copying the _current_ directory into the image again.  Newer versions of Docker will raise an error if you try this.